# django report builder not loading URLS

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Django Report Builder and am having trouble getting report builder to work.

I am running Windows 7 so the installation in the report builder documentation may or may not be right for me. Anyway the documentation which is here:

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-report-builder/latest/django-report-builder.pdf

says to:

1- pip install django-report-builder (done)

2- add report_builder to installed apps (done)

3- Add url(r’^report_builder/’, include(’report_builder.urls’)) to url.py url patterns (done)

4- ./manage.py syncdb --all

I am using Django 1.6.1 and it says that there is no --all option, so I just ran it without the all, and it created some tables.

5- ./manage.py migrate --fake report_builder

Said unknown command: migrate. I just ignored this.

So when I went to my webserver, and I get this exception:
name 'report_builder' is not defined.

I tried adding import report_builder to the url.py, but then it says 'module' object has no attribute 'urls'

I can't find any file that defines the urls attribute.

Any idea as to what's going wrong?

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Thanks, Omid. That got me past 4 and 5, but it still is not loading the report builder URLs.

Comment: Looks at my answer, updated.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. Why do I need the quotes there, but I don't need them when I import the URLS for the admin: url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)) This works

Comment: I updated my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [South](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/South/) module:

```
pip install south
```

And then adding it to `INSTALLED_APPS` of your project:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 ...
'south',
 ...
)
```

Then, run those (4,5) commands again, and now works.

But for other errors, it sounds that you using `report_builder` in `urls.py` as:

```
import report_builder

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^report_builder/', include(report_builder.urls))
)
```

That you must change it to :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^report_builder/', include('report_builder.urls'))
)
```

OR:

```
import report_builder.urls

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^report_builder/', include(report_builder.urls))
)
```

OR:

```
from report_builder import urls

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^report_builder/', include(urls))
)
```

Because `urls` module of `report_builder` is inside of `report_builder` package.

Now it's work.